# Assembly problem with simple program

Tags: linux, assembly, x86, system-calls, cpu-registers

I am trying to learn assembly from scratch. I have been reading up quite a bit, but even the following simple program I found in a reference book has me stumped:

```
section .data
msg db "Hello!", 0xa
len equ $ - msg
section .text

     global _start

_start:


move edx, len
move ecx, msg
move ebx, 1
move eax, 4
int  0x80
move ebx, 0
move eax, 1
int 0x80
```

Now apparently this is supposed to print "Hello".
But I don't even know whats happening at any of the stages.
The first two stages put the message length and messgae in two registers, which are never used again. I don't understand why.

I don't know why four different registers are needed.

Comment: The book is for what processor? What processor are you using?

Comment: I'm pretty sure its for x86 processors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`int 0x80` is a mechanism in some<sup>(a)</sup> UNIX-like operating systems for making system calls.

For these calls, the registers are used for specific values. From the `syscalls` file:

```
0 STD NOHIDE { int nosys(void); } syscall nosys_args int
1 STD NOHIDE { void exit(int rval); } exit rexit_args void
2 STD POSIX  { int fork(void); }
3 STD POSIX  { ssize_t read(int fd, void *buf, size_t nbyte); }
4 STD POSIX  { ssize_t write(int fd, const void *buf, size_t nbyte); }
```

you can see that number 4 is the `write` call and needs three other parameters. Number 1 is `exit` and needs only the return code.

When making the call, `eax` is the syscall that you're making while `ebx`, `ecx` and `edx` are the three parameters (assuming they're all needed - `exit` for example only needs one).

So, you could comment the code as follows:

```
move edx, len   ; length of message (nbyte).
move ecx, msg   ; message to print (buf).
move ebx, 1     ; file descriptor 1 (stdout).
move eax, 4     ; write syscall.
int  0x80       ; do it.

move ebx, 0     ; exit code (rval).
move eax, 1     ; exit syscall.
int 0x80        ; do it.
```

---

<sup>(a)</sup> Later versions of Linux introduced a new interface which can use different methods based on which provides the best speed. For example, some Intel chips are much faster if you use `sysenter` rather than `int 0x80`.

Comment: So when I do int 80 any commands in any registers are performed?

Comment: No, eax decides _what_ it done, the other registers are extra information that may be needed for the particular syscall specified by eax.

Comment: So eax, ebx, ecx and edx are not "general" as I believed, they have different purposes? I couldn't do move eax, msg?

Comment: That's right, eax is the syscall number itself, ebx is the _first_ parameter (return value for exit, file descriptor for read and write, not used for fork), ecx is the _second_ parameter (not used for exit, buffer address for read and write) and so on.

Comment: As a side question. Nothing in my program was "pushed". Does that mean the stack wasn't used at all?

Comment: @JJG: Correct. That's dictated by the calling convention. Code _may_ push parameters on the stack but it's by no means _required_. Sometimes registers are more efficient, especially if the amount of information being passed is small.

Answer (score 1):

IIRC the `int 0x80` instruction is used to invoke a syscall by using the interrupt vector. In your example the values in `ebx` and `eax` are used to specify which syscall you are gonna call (probably the print operation on stdout).

The syscall knows by convenction that `edx` and `ecx` should contain what is gonna be printed.

Answer (score 1):

On many systems, [int 80h](http://www.int80h.org/) is the [system call](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call) gate. The syscall number is in `eax`. `ebx`, `ecx` and `edx` contain additional parameters:

```
move edx, len
move ecx, msg
move ebx, 1    ; fd 1 is stdout
move eax, 4    ; syscall 4 is write
int  0x80      ; write(1, msg, len)
move ebx, 0
move eax, 1    ; syscall 1 is exit
int 0x80       ; exit(0)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. So what does move ebx, 0 and move eax, 1 do? And one more question: Why do I need to specify the lenght of the message?

Comment: `ebx` is the parameter passed to `exit()`, i.e. `0` (success). You need to specify the length of the message because `write()` works with arbitrary binary data, not null-terminated strings.

Comment: I was under the impression eax,ebx,ecx and edx were geneal purpose registers. What is the difference between using them?

Comment: It's just a [calling convention](http://www.int80h.org/bsdasm/#alternate-calling-convention). The registers themselves are not special.

Answer (score 0):

When you call a system call, the 'int' mnemonic, a system interruption is generated. It kinda "jumps" to a system function, which, in this case, prints output (depends on eax).

This interruption uses all those registers to know what to do. The interrupt reads eax, check what function you want and uses the other registers to do so.

eax is the function number, 4 means sys_write, which writes a string to a stream/file descriptor.

Now it knows you want to write something to some place, then it uses the other registers to those informations.

for eax = 4 and int 0x80 this is the meaning for the other registers:

ebx = output (1 = stdout)
ecx = address of the string
edx = length of the string

You can read this:

http://www.intel.com/Assets/ja_JP/PDF/manual/253665.pdf

Section 6.4
It has some stuff about Interruptins and Exceptions.

And you can start writing Intel 80x86 assembly code, which is simpler and easier to understand, here are some links:

Mnemonics/Code tables cheatsheet:
http://www.jegerlehner.ch/intel/

Some introduction sites:
http://mysite.du.edu/~etuttle/math/8086.htm
http://www.malware.org/teaching/assembly.htm